# If file is not overwritten then quit installer

Tags: file, installation, nsis, overwrite

I am using:

```
; Set output path to the installation directory.
SetOutPath $INSTDIR\

SetOverwrite on

; Put file there
File "ACC\*.APP"
```

to overwrite a file, but if the file can't be overwritten, then I want that the installer quits, how to do this?

Does Error Flag value needs to be used? But how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The File command sets the error flag
>   if overwrite mode is set to 'try' and
>   the file could not be overwritten, or
>   if the overwrite mode is set to 'on'
>   and the file could not be overwritten
>   and the user selects ignore

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
ClearErrors
SetOverwrite try
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
File "ACC\*.APP"
${If} ${Errors}
  Quit
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: sir, can i check that whether a file is open?

Comment: SIR, also , can the error dialog which appears when the file can't be overwritten, can it be bypassed and directly the installer be quit. i don't want to display that dialog, that is, i dont want that the user is able to press Abort, Retry , or Ignore button , but when overwrite fails, then a message box appears, saying, failed, and it quits

Comment: @sqlchild: Use "SetOverwrite try"

Comment: if i specify "try", then it tries to overwrite, but i dont want it to try, i just want that it quits without saying anything. actually, in my case , i want that , when the software is running then if the user runs the installer to update the software , then it quits, because the software is open.

Comment: sir , is bypassing the error dialog possible, if am using "on" in SetOverwrite